# Sinclair ZX Spectrum with DivMMC load issue

Tags: z80, zx-spectrum, divmmc

I use a Sinclair ZX Spectrum Issue 2 with a DivMMC EnJOY! Pro One
and the boot process shows no error and I'm even able to enter the
file browser but if I choose any game/demo/program I get always garbage:

YouTube Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bGBzDCBbKk

Here my CPU (NEC D780C-1) with modification:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/syNPq.jpg

Any idea what's wrong here?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the real issue was a problem with memory!

based on the `ZX Spectrum Service Manual` I did a RAM test:

Execute the command `PRINT PEEK 23732+PEEK 23733*256` and the result should
be `65535`! (for a 48k machine)

I got `49344` -> error in `49345`: (shows always the last working address)

1. key in: `POKE 49345,85: PRINT PEEK 49345 (=A)`
2. key in: `POKE 49345,170: PRINT PEEK 49345 (=B)`

If answer A is anything other than 85 or answer B other than 170 look into 
this table to find the faulty RAM IC: (mine was **IC16**)

[image]

So I have replaced the faulty IC16 and now I'm able to work with DivMMC!

Answer (score 4):

Does your divmmc work in another machine?

Anyway, there is a single common problem in 48k spectrums: on the edge connector, +12v and /M1 signals are neighbouring. When some device is inserted too much unaligned, chances are that +12v would shortcircuit to /M1.

Since 48k "chipset" does not use /M1, with enough luck this could pass unnoticed to the user -- the machine still works, but /M1 output is burned out. And DivMMC needs /M1 anyway.

The only way to fix that is to replace Z80.

Comment: Ok,thank you! Which Z80 do you suggest and is the existent modification (see picture) also needed with the replacement?

Comment: First, you obviously have to be sure the problem indeed in burned out /M1 signal. If it is the case, just swap it to any Z80 NMOS cpu around, the only restriction is maximum frequency, that have to be greater than 3.5 MHz (4MHz or more).

Comment: Once I'd swapped burned CPU to CMOS type, and everything worked just fine. However, CMOS Z80 do execute the undocumented command "OUT (C),0" in the 'wrong' way, as "OUT (C),#FF". So two or three thoughtlessly written software titles might break with CMOS Z80.

Comment: And the final note: you just keep wires soldered where they were before the CPU swap. They have nothing to do with CPU, rather they fix some bugs in the board layout.

Comment: Ok, thx! Last question: what's the best way to be sure that my CPU has this /M1 issue?

Comment: The best way is to use oscilloscope or logic analyzer.